# Dynamic records key type

Tags: dhall

I'm trying to generate some YAML containing a map with dynamic keys, as described [here](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/wiki/Getting-started%3A-Generate-JSON-or-YAML#dynamic-records). This works if I use `Text` keys, but not when the keys have any other type. I'd like to use a union type for the keys if possible.

I've tried using different types for `mapKey`, including a union type and `Natural`, but with no success. I can work around the problem by converting all `mapKey` values to `Text`, but this isn't ideal.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
let Union = <A | B>
in
[{mapKey = Union.A, mapValue = "foo"}]
```

I'd expect it to generate YAML to be:

```
A: foo
```

but instead, the generated YAML looks like this:

```
- mapKey: A
  mapValue: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question inspired adding this feature, which will be available in the next release (Version 1.25.0).  See:

https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/pull/1094

This will also work in the other direction, meaning that `{json,yaml}-to-dhall` will be able to decode record keys into a union if requested to by the schema:

```
$ json-to-dhall 'List { mapKey : < A | B >, mapValue : Natural }' <<< '{"A": 1, "B": 2}'
[ { mapKey = < A | B >.A, mapValue = 1 }, { mapKey = < A | B >.B, mapValue = 2 } ]
```